# Trying to understand UnmappedInstanceError using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to fill a table in SQL with data in the dataframe below. The code functions as expected when I use other dataframes with exactly the same Columns and datatypes, but for this dataframe alone the error `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.list' is not mapped` results from the line `session.add([yc_node_hist(fk_yc_update = listofindices3[i],curve_date = row1['Date'], tenor = row1['Year'], Abrv = row1['VALUE'])])` . I am using `automap()` to map the table `yc_node_hist` to a Class. **My main problem is that I can't understand what exactly the Error means**.

```
             Date        Year      VALUE     ABBRV
0      2005-01-04  0.08333333   4.709456      GBP
1      2005-01-05  0.08333333   4.713099      GBP
2      2005-01-06  0.08333333   4.707237      GBP
3      2005-01-07  0.08333333   4.705043      GBP
```

`yc_node_hist`:

```
create table yc_node_hist
(
    id bigint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    fk_yc_update bigint NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES yc_update(id),
    curve_date date NOT NULL,
    tenor float NOT NULL,
    Abrv float NOT NULL
)
```

The code I am using:

```
engine2 = YieldData.Connectionengine()
session = Session(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False)
for (i1, row1), (i2, row2) in pairwise(df.iterrows()):
    if row1['ABBRV'] == row2['ABBRV'] and isinstance(row1['VALUE'], float)==1:
        print(row1)
        session.add([yc_node_hist(fk_yc_update = listofindices3[i],curve_date = row1['Date'], tenor = row1['Year'], Abrv = row1['VALUE'])])
```